# Timing on setInterval doesn't seem accurate

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I am writing some javascript to change the opacity of an image that is currently displayed so that it seems to fade and then it changes the image to a different one. I have the `setInterval` for the image changing set to wait 5000ms. The `setInterval` for the fade is set to start at 4000ms. The `setTimeout` is called 10 times all waiting for 100ms making up the difference between the time that the fading `setInterval` waits up front and the time that the ChangeImage `setInverval` waits up front.

```
var num, lastNum = 0, count = 10, tcount = 0.0;
var file = "images/image-", ext = ".jpg", image, temp;
var f1 = "alpha(opacity=", f2 = ")";

window.onload = setTimeout(Initialize, 0);
window.onload = setInterval(ImageFader, 4000);
window.onload = setInterval(ChangeImage, 5000);

function Initialize()
{
    image = document.getElementById('title-image');
    image.src = "images/image-1.jpg";
}

function ChangeImage()
{
    image = document.getElementById('title-image');
    do
    {
        num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    } while (num == lastNum);
    lastNum = num;
    temp = file.concat(num.toString());
    image.src = temp.concat(ext);
}

function ImageFader()
{
    setTimeout(Fade, 100);
}

function Fade()
{
    tcount = count / 10;
    image.style.opacity = tcount;
    f1 = f1.concat((tcount * 100).toString());
    image.style.filter = f1.concat(f2);

    if (count > 1)
    {
        count--;
        setTimeout(Fade, 100);
    }
    else
    {
        count = 10;
        image.style.opacity = 1;
        image.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=100)";
    }
}
```

I'm really confused why the times are not matching up as they should. The fading for the first image is timed well. Where it fades and then moves to the next image at the right time. But from there on, the timing becomes out of sync. The fading happens but the image doesn't change at the right time.

Comment: They are [never guaranteed to be accurate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified), if exact time is important use _Date_

Comment: @PaulS. Thanks Paul. I'll take a look at that. It's easy to fix what I have with a couple changes but I was just not sure why this method was working the way it seemed like it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to work around using the separate setInverval() methods for the fade and the image change:

```
window.onload = setTimeout(Initialize, 0);
window.onload = setInterval(ImageFader, 8000);

function Initialize()
{
    image = document.getElementById('title-image');
    image.src = "images/image-1.jpg";
}

function ChangeImage()
{
    image = document.getElementById('title-image');
    do
    {
        num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    } while (num == lastNum);
    lastNum = num;
    temp = file.concat(num.toString());
    image.src = temp.concat(ext);
}

function ImageFader()
{
    setTimeout(Fade, 100);
}

function Fade()
{
    tcount = count / 10;
    image.style.opacity = tcount;
    f1 = f1.concat((tcount * 100).toString());
    image.style.filter = f1.concat(f2);

    if (count > 1)
    {
        count--;
        setTimeout(Fade, 100);
    }
    else
    {
        count = 10;
        ChangeImage();
        image.style.opacity = 1;
        image.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=100)";
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `setInterval()` alongside `setTimeout()` (or several timeouts), they run independently and then one may overlap each other. Please look my answer, you're almost there.

Answer (score 0):

Execution time of the `Fade()` method will definitely be part of the problem.

Also the environment you're in.
[Real-time operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system) promise to perform things by a certain time, and execute them on time every time.  (With some exceptions.  I'm simplifying.)

Similarly embedded systems without any OS can be very predictable - because there's nothing happening between lines of code.  If you can determine precisely how many CPU cycles occur between point A and point B, you can guarantee that everything will happen on time.

What you're doing is trying to achieve such exact timings with a non-real-time operating system, in an environment as far away from an embedded system as possible!

*Even if* we ignore the reality that your operating system (hosting the browser) is never guaranteeing things will happen when you want them to (which you just can't solve in JS in a browser like this) you've still got a problem - the `setTimeout(Fade, 100)` line is actually giving you more like 100.5ms delay, because all this code has to execute first:

```
tcount = count / 10;
image.style.opacity = tcount;
f1 = f1.concat((tcount * 100).toString());
image.style.filter = f1.concat(f2);

if (count > 1)
{ ...
```

(I hope that makes sense.  Every line of code in that function leading up to the `setTimeout(...)` takes time to execute, is my point.)

If your problem is solely that the *relative timings* of the two functions are out (rather than 5000ms is never going to be precisely 5000ms), then there's a very simple solution.

**Do everything from one timer.**  :-)

Create one "clock" which has an interval of a common division of all the other clock intervals.  100ms is sufficient in your case, because it can be multiplied by whole numbers into 5000ms, 4000ms and 100ms.

Scrap all these other lines of code:

```
window.onload = setTimeout(Initialize, 0);
window.onload = setInterval(ImageFader, 4000);
window.onload = setInterval(ChangeImage, 5000);
```

Instead count the executions of one single 100ms clock.  50 executions of that clock should trigger `ChangeImage`, 40 executions should trigger `ImageFader`, etc.

That'll give you precise *relative* timings.

---

**Update to include sample pseudo code:**

```
var clockCount = 0;
var fading = false;

setTimeout(globalClock, 100);
function globalClock(
   clockCount++;

   if (clockCount == 40) {
      ImageFader();
   } elseif (clockCount == 50) {
      ChangeImage();
   }

   if (fading) {
      Fade();
   }

   // At end of function so we don't ever trigger multiple executions at the same time
   setTimeout(globalClock, 100);
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `setInterval()` calls, use a `setTimeout()` only, organizing all timers to the chain:

1. Call `setTimeout(Fade, 4000)` in the end of `Initialize()`.
2. Call `setTimeout(Fade, 100)` from the `Fade()` itself several times, but `setTimeout(ChangeImage, 100)` at the last step there.
3. Call `setTimeout(Fade, 4000)` in the end of `ChangeImage()`.